# Handle relational data in classes without use of database

Tags: c#, oop

I have some relational data i.e.

1. source (having many categories)
2. categories (having many products)
3. products

Now, how can I handle this using classes in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create them as POCOs (simple C# classes that just contain the data definitions) e.g.

```
class source
{
    public List<category> Categories = new List<category>();
}

class category
{
    public category(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public List<product> Products = new List<product>();

}

class product
{
    public product(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then to test:

```
    static void test()
    {
        product spoon = new product("spoon");

        category cutlery = new category("cutlery");
        cutlery.Products.Add(spoon);

        source mystuff = new source();
        mystuff.Categories.Add(cutlery);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- *Source* should have a collection of *categories*
- *Category* should have a collection of *products*.
- *Products* is only used by *category* and does not "know" about the
  other two.

Comment: This is one option but the relations could be symmetrical: Product could have a Category property, Category could have a Source property.

Comment: Is the use of dataset is correct in this context having relationship between datatables ?

Answer (score 1):

You need two classes `Category` and `Product`. Each `Product` has a property `Category` to which it belongs. 
You can store them in a `Dictionary<Category, List<Product>>`, then you can lookup all products of a given category easily.

Here is a possible implementation where you can use these classes even as key in a dictionary because they override `GetHashCode`:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CategoryId.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Category c2 = obj as Category;
        if (c2 == null) return false;
        return CategoryId == c2.CategoryId;
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    publlic Category Category { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ProductId.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Product p2 = obj as Product;
        if (p2 == null) return false;
        return ProductId == p2.ProductId;
    }
}
```

Initialization (normally from DAL):

```
var cat1 = new Category(){CategoryId=1,Name="ABC"};
var cat2 = new Category(){CategoryId=2,Name="DEF"};

var products1 = new List<Product>(){
    new Product(){ProductId=1,Name="Prod1",Category=cat1},
    new Product(){ProductId=2,Name="Prod2",Category=cat1},
    new Product(){ProductId=3,Name="Prod3",Category=cat1}
};
var products2 = new List<Product>(){
    new Product(){ProductId=4,Name="Prod4",Category=cat2},
    new Product(){ProductId=5,Name="Prod5",Category=cat2},
};

var categoryProducts = new Dictionary<Category, List<Product>>()
{
    { cat1, products1},
    { cat2, products2}
};
```

Now you can lookup all products of a given category:

```
List<Product> products = categoryProducts[cat1];
```

The source could be a `List<Category>`:

```
var source = new List<Category>();
// fill from DAL
foreach(Category cat in source)
    foreach(Product product in categoryProducts[cat])
        Console.WriteLine("Category:{0} Product:{1}", cat.Name, product.Name);
```